# how to check if session has no datatable in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datatable

I have a session that stores DataTable in it. It might not be the best idea but It works perfectly for me. My problem is that I know how to check a Session for string if it is empty or null. But I dont know how to check Session if it has datatable in it or not

here is my code to check if session has string in it

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["stok_kodu"] as string))
```

Unfortunately, DataTable class doesnt have a "IsNullOrEmpty" function like below.

```
// this is wrong
if (!DataTable.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["stok_kodu"] as DataTable))
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try getting the DataTable using [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) and if you get `null` back that means that the DataTable doesn't exist in the session.

```
DataTable dt = Session["stok_kodu"] as DataTable;
if(dt  != null)
{
  //DataTable exists
}
else
{
 //DataTable doesn't exist
}
```

**For Strings.**

Your check for string values using `IsNullOrEmpty` doesn't really tell you whether the key exists in the session or not. If It is an empty string but it does exist in the session you will get a result indicating it doesn't. Simply check it against `null` to see if the key exists.